# UILocalNotification on Fri and Sat

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, notifications, localnotification

How do you set a UILocalNotification to fire every Fri and Sat at 8pm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are not able to set a custom repeat interval on local notifications yet.

The best solution is to schedule two weekly notifications !

The fire date of the first one will be next friday at 8pm and the fire date of the second one will be next saturday at 8pm.

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a bug report/enhancement at http://bugreport.apple.com/

You may take a look at my report archived at Open Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=759402

According to Marco, developer of Instapaper, Apple prioritizes enhancement and feature requests partly based on how many developers are requesting them.

If this feature is important to you I urge you to file a report as well.